Unable to login to Ubuntu 24.04
I'm unable to login to Ubuntu 24.04. When trying to login I get this  screen.


https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Does this answer your question? After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: "Oh no! Something went wrong"

Just installed 24.04 two times, the password is not accepted at subsequent login
the only working solution was to enter recovery mode and use passwd to set a new password.

This just happened to me ( Exactly the same as above when trying to login as xorg ) or if I tried normally you would end up in a continuous loop login
I didnt want to re-install everything.
The quickfix solution which worked for me was.

reboot in safe mode
enable network ( if you able to connect through ethernet cable)
drop to the terminal
apt install ubuntu-desktop task-gnome-desktop
Then
Reboot and then when login select not the Gnome desktop but your Ubuntu ( or xorg Ubuntu  which ever you were using ) and your back to where you were before..
Why .... I have no idea


Just setup a new machine with the latest version of the Image for 24.04 LTS. Every time, I am using a complex password for the login (setting it as part of the setup-process) the login is impossible.
The only solution is -

starting with a weak password (no special characters, just asdf1234 or something similar).
login in and changing immediatly the display-manager (sudo dpkg-reconfigur gdm3)
Reboot system
Login again and change the password -  now you can use a safe password.
This is the first time I'm observing this. All LTS-Versions before haven't had such a problem.
Maybe that could be fixed in the 24.04.04? ;)

Thank you very much in advance!
Best Regards

Here is my experience with this when I installed 24.04 on VirtualBox on a Mac.
The issue appears to involve the Gnome Desktop.  I changed the display-manager/desktop to lightdm using this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-default-display-manager-in-ubuntu/
I was able to login by adding a new username/password in "recovery mode" as explained here:  How do I reset a lost administrative password?
I was able to login with the new username and use the terminal command su myusername and then used sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm to change the display-manager/desktop.

Just delete the user environment settings folder.
rm .rf ~/.local

contr + alt + f3 Terminal login is possible

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
